# Name Of Time Travel Romantic Movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie on Netflix Instant (US) in Summer 2013 but do not recall the name of it.  All I remember is the plot.  I have searched the internet and I am beginning to think that the movie does not exist and that I imagined the whole thing.  Here is the plot:

**Edit: Since I found the name of the movie, I hid what I originally written since it gives away the ending.**

> The movie opens with a man getting into a car accident.  He is then
>  seen waking up as a much younger version of himself.  He has a best
>  friend who is a girl.  Later on he becomes a wedding photographer,
>  falls in love with his best friend, and they get married and get a
>  dog.  He has a contentious relationship with his doctor father for
>  some reason.  Towards the end of the movie, you find out that the
>  whole movie was the man's life flashing before his eyes.  You think he
>  is going to die, but he does not.  Everyone lives happily ever after.

The movie is NOT any of the following:

- The Time Traveller's Wife
- TiMER
- Happy Accidents
- About Time
- Safety Not Guaranteed
- Premonition
- Any of the movies listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_travel_science_fiction)

Comment: do you recall any of the actors by any chance?

Comment: Can you not look at your Netflix history online?

Comment: I do not recall any of the actors.  The Netflix history only goes back 100 items.  I watched this movie last summer so it is since long fallen off my history list.

Comment: The problem might be that it's not actually a time travel movie since it ends up just being a flash back.

Comment: Maybe. But I remember something specific in the description being a time travel movie. Calling it a flashback movie would give away the ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.  The suggestion by @Leatherwing led me to finding it.  Although Netflix only keeps the last 100 items viewed in your history, it does allow you to view a list of everything that you rated at http://www.netflix.com/MoviesYouveSeen . I rate everything I watch (and then some) and found the title:

> **Shuffle**
>
> While looking into his wife's murder, a narcoleptic man finds
>   his investigation stymied when he suddenly begins living his life out
>   of sequence.

Netflix Streaming: http://www.netflix.com/WiMovie/70242974

IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1488594/

I remembered it being about time travel because every time the main character goes to sleep, he wakes up a different age in his life.  So it is not about time travel explicitly, but implicitly.  It is probably not listed in Wikipedia because it was an independent film and did not get a wide release.